# Mysql INSERT and DELETE in a single statement with dependant on eachother

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have the following two queries. Second query is dependent on first one.

```
$query1 = mysql_query("Insert into table_one set ---- ");
if($query1)
{
   $query2 = mysql_query("delete from table_two where condition---");
   if($query2)
   {
      $message = "both queries executed successfully";
   }
   else
   {
      $del = mysql_query("delete record inserted by $query1");
   }
}
```

Can we execute these two queries in a single statement so that both queries depend on each other.
**If INSERT query fail, DELETE query also fail it's execution as well as if DELETE query fail INSERTION in query first fail.**

Thanks

Comment: You use transactions. These can be rolled back upon failure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67257741/2943403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I good understand what you need, simply use transactions.
Run this query before your insertion:

```
mysql_query('begin');
```

And then, if everything went fine, commit the transaction:

```
mysql_query('commit');
```

In case of any failures, you may rollback every change you made:

```
mysql_query('rollback');
```

Note that in case of MySQL, the MyISAM engine does not support rollback in transactions, so use InnoDB.

Read more about transactions here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Example with your code:

```
<?PHP

mysql_query('begin'); //start transaction
$query1 = mysql_query("Insert into table_one set ---- ");
if($query1)
{
   $query2 = mysql_query("delete from table_two where condition---");
   if($query2)
   {
      mysql_query('commit'); //both queries went fine, so let's save your changes and end the transaction
      $message = "both queries executed successfully";
   }
   else
   {
      mysql_query('rollback'); //query2 failed, so let's rollback changes made by query1 and end the transaction
   }
}
else
    mysql_query('rollback'); //query1 failed, so let's end the transaction
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Sir please guide me how i will use these two queries asked in question with begin , commit and rollback

Comment: problem solved thank for help, but sir i have a little question more that can we do the same task and run all above queries in a single `mysql_query("statement");`

Comment: `mysql_query` supports only one statement at once, so no. But there is something like `mysqli_multi_query`, but you would need (and you should) to change all mysql_* functions to mysqli_* functions.

Comment: dear please check my answer , and tell me whether this solution is perfect or not, actually my answer is updated form of your answer

Answer (score 1):

If query2 fails it doesn't check query1.

```
$query1 = mysql_query("Insert into table_one set ---- ");
$query2 = mysql_query("delete from table_two where condition---");
if( $query2 && $query1)
{

      $message = "both queries executed successfully";
}
else if(!$query2)
   {
      $del = mysql_query("delete record inserted by $query1");
   }
```

Comment: thanks for replying, you give me good idea, this concept is fine when both queries done successfully but in-case second query fails what will be the the query `$del = mysql_query("delete record inserted by $query1");`

Comment: if query2 fails then it does't go further. If it doesn't  fail then query1 will be executed. I think it solves your probem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use transaction, if any query fails then call rollback, otherwise commit

Comment: Please give me a little concept how to use it, I am new to it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a best solution. 

Extending idea of @Luki i wrote the following code and it give me too much satisfied answer. First use the following function.

```
function multi_statement()
{
    global $conn;
    $total_args = func_get_args();
    $args = implode($total_args,";");
    $args = "begin;".$args.";commit;";
    $number = 0;
    if($conn->multi_query($args))
    {
        do
        {
            if ($conn->more_results())
            {
                $number++;
            }
        }
        while($conn->next_result());
    }
    if($number < (count($total_args)+1))
    {
        $conn->query('rollback');
        echo "Sorry..!!! Error found in Query no:".$number;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "All queries executed successfully";
    }
}
```

Then I called the function with number of statements, all these statements are dependent on each other. In-case there is error in any query, no one query occur any changes in database.

```
    $statement1 = "INSERT INTO `pic_gall`.`admin` (`admin_id`, `username`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, 'as1', 'as1')";
    $statement2 = "INSERT INTO `pic_gall`.`admin` (`admin_id`, `username`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, 'as2', 'as2')";
    $statement3 = "INSERT INTO `pic_gall`.`admin` (`admin_id`, `username`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, 'as3', 'as3')";
    $statement4 = "INSERT INTO `pic_gall`.`admin` (`admin_id`, `username`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, 'as4', 'as4')";
    $statement5 = "DELETE from user where user_id = '12'";
multi_statement($statement1,$statement2,$statement3,$statement4,$statement5);
```